# Add list values to a new list

Tags: python, list, numpy, variables, append

I'm working on a code that starts defining four lists containing stock analysis indicator' parameters:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

RSI_parameter=[range(13,16,1),range(70,80,5),range(25,35,5)]
RSI_parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*RSI_parameter))

Bollinger_parameter=[range(20,35,1),np.arange(2,3,0.25)]
Bollinger_parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*Bollinger_parameter))

MACD_parameter=[range(11,14,1),range(25,27,1),range(9,11,1)]
MACD_parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*MACD_parameter))

EMA_parameter=[range(20,21,1),range(50,51,1),np.arange(0,0.01,0.002)]
EMA_parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*EMA_parameter))
```

Next I attempt to create a new list of all the combinations  of the indicators:

```
indiclist=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    for item in itertools.combinations(('RSI','Bollinger','MACD','EMA'),i):
        indiclist.append(list(item))
print(indiclist)
```

Finally (and this is the part where I'm having trouble), I try to create a new list, called param, where I will have all the parameters for a certain combination of indicators...using the following code:

```
param=[]
par=[]
for ind in indiclist:
    for i in ind:
        param.append(i+'_parameter_list')
        print(param)
```

I get this output:

```
['RSI_parameter_list']
['RSI_parameter_list', 'Bollinger_parameter_list']
['RSI_parameter_list', 'Bollinger_parameter_list', 'MACD_parameter_list']
['RSI_parameter_list', 'Bollinger_parameter_list', 'MACD_parameter_list', 'EMA_parameter_list']
['RSI_parameter_list', 'Bollinger_parameter_list', 'MACD_parameter_list', 'EMA_parameter_list', 'RSI_parameter_list']
```

But I would like to get this output:

```
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)], [(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)]
[(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), (20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)] (...)]
```

Comment: You never save `par=itertools.product(*param)`, assuming that this is the output you want?

Comment: Strings are not the same as variables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am using a dictionary `my_dict` to store the **parameter lists**. Then for all combinations in `indiclist[]`, creating another list `params[]` that contains your expected output. Please look at the following code:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

RSI_parameter=[range(13,16,1),range(70,80,5),range(25,35,5)]
RSI_parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*RSI_parameter))

Bollinger_parameter=[range(20,35,1),np.arange(2,3,0.25)]
Bollinger_parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*Bollinger_parameter))

MACD_parameter=[range(11,14,1),range(25,27,1),range(9,11,1)]
MACD_parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*MACD_parameter))

EMA_parameter=[range(20,21,1),range(50,51,1),np.arange(0,0.01,0.002)]
EMA_parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*EMA_parameter))


# dictinary containing all parameter lists
my_dict = {
    'RSI': RSI_parameter_list,
    'Bollinger': Bollinger_parameter_list,
    'MACD': MACD_parameter_list,
    'EMA': EMA_parameter_list
}

# combinations of the indicators:
indiclist=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    for item in itertools.combinations(('RSI','Bollinger','MACD','EMA'),i):
        indiclist.append(list(item))

# have all the parameters for a certain combination of indicators
params = []
for combination in indiclist:
    inner_list = []
    for indicator in combination:
        inner_list.append(my_dict[indicator])
    params.append(inner_list)
```

to see all possible combinations and their parameters together, execute the following code:

```
for i in range(len(params)):
    print(indiclist[i]) # comment out this line to get the exact output you want
    print(params[i],end="\n\n")
```

Output:

```
['RSI']
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)]]

['Bollinger']
[[(20, 2.0), (20, 2.25), (20, 2.5), (20, 2.75), (21, 2.0), (21, 2.25), (21, 2.5), (21, 2.75), (22, 2.0), (22, 2.25), (22, 2.5), (22, 2.75), (23, 2.0), (23, 2.25), (23, 2.5), (23, 2.75), (24, 2.0), (24, 2.25), (24, 2.5), (24, 2.75), (25, 2.0), (25, 2.25), (25, 2.5), (25, 2.75), (26, 2.0), (26, 2.25), (26, 2.5), (26, 2.75), (27, 2.0), (27, 2.25), (27, 2.5), (27, 2.75), (28, 2.0), (28, 2.25), (28, 2.5), (28, 2.75), (29, 2.0), (29, 2.25), (29, 2.5), (29, 2.75), (30, 2.0), (30, 2.25), (30, 2.5), (30, 2.75), (31, 2.0), (31, 2.25), (31, 2.5), (31, 2.75), (32, 2.0), (32, 2.25), (32, 2.5), (32, 2.75), (33, 2.0), (33, 2.25), (33, 2.5), (33, 2.75), (34, 2.0), (34, 2.25), (34, 2.5), (34, 2.75)]]

['MACD']
[[(11, 25, 9), (11, 25, 10), (11, 26, 9), (11, 26, 10), (12, 25, 9), (12, 25, 10), (12, 26, 9), (12, 26, 10), (13, 25, 9), (13, 25, 10), (13, 26, 9), (13, 26, 10)]]

['EMA']
[[(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), (20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)]]

['RSI', 'Bollinger']
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)], [(20, 2.0), (20, 2.25), (20, 2.5), (20, 2.75), (21, 2.0), (21, 2.25), (21, 2.5), (21, 2.75), (22, 2.0), (22, 2.25), (22, 2.5), (22, 2.75), (23, 2.0), (23, 2.25), (23, 2.5), (23, 2.75), (24, 2.0), (24, 2.25), (24, 2.5), (24, 2.75), (25, 2.0), (25, 2.25), (25, 2.5), (25, 2.75), (26, 2.0), (26, 2.25), (26, 2.5), (26, 2.75), (27, 2.0), (27, 2.25), (27, 2.5), (27, 2.75), (28, 2.0), (28, 2.25), (28, 2.5), (28, 2.75), (29, 2.0), (29, 2.25), (29, 2.5), (29, 2.75), (30, 2.0), (30, 2.25), (30, 2.5), (30, 2.75), (31, 2.0), (31, 2.25), (31, 2.5), (31, 2.75), (32, 2.0), (32, 2.25), (32, 2.5), (32, 2.75), (33, 2.0), (33, 2.25), (33, 2.5), (33, 2.75), (34, 2.0), (34, 2.25), (34, 2.5), (34, 2.75)]]

['RSI', 'MACD']
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)], [(11, 25, 9), (11, 25, 10), (11, 26, 9), 
(11, 26, 10), (12, 25, 9), (12, 25, 10), (12, 26, 9), (12, 26, 10), (13, 25, 9), (13, 25, 10), (13, 26, 9), (13, 26, 10)]]

['RSI', 'EMA']
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)], [(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), (20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)]]

['Bollinger', 'MACD']
[[(20, 2.0), (20, 2.25), (20, 2.5), (20, 2.75), (21, 2.0), (21, 2.25), (21, 2.5), (21, 2.75), (22, 2.0), (22, 2.25), (22, 2.5), (22, 2.75), (23, 2.0), (23, 2.25), (23, 2.5), (23, 2.75), (24, 2.0), (24, 2.25), (24, 2.5), (24, 2.75), (25, 2.0), (25, 2.25), (25, 2.5), (25, 2.75), (26, 2.0), (26, 2.25), (26, 2.5), (26, 2.75), (27, 2.0), (27, 2.25), (27, 2.5), (27, 2.75), (28, 2.0), (28, 2.25), (28, 2.5), (28, 2.75), (29, 2.0), (29, 2.25), (29, 2.5), (29, 2.75), (30, 2.0), (30, 2.25), (30, 2.5), (30, 2.75), (31, 2.0), (31, 2.25), (31, 2.5), (31, 2.75), (32, 2.0), (32, 2.25), (32, 2.5), (32, 2.75), (33, 2.0), (33, 2.25), (33, 2.5), (33, 2.75), (34, 2.0), (34, 2.25), (34, 2.5), (34, 2.75)], [(11, 25, 9), (11, 25, 10), (11, 26, 9), (11, 26, 10), (12, 25, 9), (12, 25, 10), (12, 26, 9), (12, 26, 10), (13, 25, 9), (13, 25, 10), (13, 26, 9), (13, 26, 10)]]

['Bollinger', 'EMA']
[[(20, 2.0), (20, 2.25), (20, 2.5), (20, 2.75), (21, 2.0), (21, 2.25), (21, 2.5), (21, 2.75), (22, 2.0), (22, 2.25), (22, 2.5), (22, 2.75), (23, 2.0), (23, 2.25), (23, 2.5), (23, 2.75), (24, 2.0), (24, 2.25), (24, 2.5), (24, 2.75), (25, 2.0), (25, 2.25), (25, 2.5), (25, 2.75), (26, 2.0), (26, 2.25), (26, 2.5), (26, 2.75), (27, 2.0), (27, 2.25), (27, 2.5), (27, 2.75), (28, 2.0), (28, 2.25), (28, 2.5), (28, 2.75), (29, 2.0), (29, 2.25), (29, 2.5), (29, 2.75), (30, 2.0), (30, 2.25), (30, 2.5), (30, 2.75), (31, 2.0), (31, 2.25), (31, 2.5), (31, 2.75), (32, 2.0), (32, 2.25), (32, 2.5), (32, 2.75), (33, 2.0), (33, 2.25), (33, 2.5), (33, 2.75), (34, 2.0), (34, 2.25), (34, 2.5), (34, 2.75)], [(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), (20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)]]

['MACD', 'EMA']
[[(11, 25, 9), (11, 25, 10), (11, 26, 9), (11, 26, 10), (12, 25, 9), (12, 25, 10), (12, 26, 9), (12, 26, 10), (13, 25, 9), (13, 25, 10), (13, 26, 9), (13, 26, 10)], [(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), (20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)]]

['RSI', 'Bollinger', 'MACD']
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)], [(20, 2.0), (20, 2.25), (20, 2.5), (20, 2.75), (21, 2.0), (21, 2.25), (21, 2.5), (21, 2.75), (22, 2.0), (22, 2.25), (22, 2.5), (22, 2.75), (23, 2.0), (23, 2.25), (23, 2.5), (23, 2.75), (24, 2.0), (24, 2.25), (24, 2.5), (24, 2.75), (25, 2.0), (25, 2.25), (25, 2.5), (25, 2.75), (26, 2.0), (26, 2.25), (26, 2.5), (26, 2.75), (27, 2.0), (27, 2.25), (27, 2.5), (27, 2.75), (28, 2.0), (28, 2.25), (28, 2.5), (28, 2.75), (29, 2.0), (29, 2.25), (29, 2.5), (29, 2.75), (30, 2.0), (30, 2.25), (30, 2.5), (30, 2.75), (31, 2.0), (31, 2.25), (31, 2.5), (31, 2.75), (32, 2.0), (32, 2.25), (32, 2.5), (32, 2.75), (33, 2.0), (33, 2.25), (33, 2.5), (33, 2.75), (34, 2.0), (34, 2.25), (34, 2.5), (34, 2.75)], [(11, 25, 9), (11, 25, 10), (11, 26, 9), (11, 26, 10), (12, 25, 9), (12, 25, 10), (12, 26, 
9), (12, 26, 10), (13, 25, 9), (13, 25, 10), (13, 26, 9), (13, 26, 10)]]

['RSI', 'Bollinger', 'EMA']
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)], [(20, 2.0), (20, 2.25), (20, 2.5), (20, 2.75), (21, 2.0), (21, 2.25), (21, 2.5), (21, 2.75), (22, 2.0), (22, 2.25), (22, 2.5), (22, 2.75), (23, 2.0), (23, 2.25), (23, 2.5), (23, 2.75), (24, 2.0), (24, 2.25), (24, 2.5), (24, 2.75), (25, 2.0), (25, 2.25), (25, 2.5), (25, 2.75), (26, 2.0), (26, 2.25), (26, 2.5), (26, 2.75), (27, 2.0), (27, 2.25), (27, 2.5), (27, 2.75), (28, 2.0), (28, 2.25), (28, 2.5), (28, 2.75), (29, 2.0), (29, 2.25), (29, 2.5), (29, 2.75), (30, 2.0), (30, 2.25), (30, 2.5), (30, 2.75), (31, 2.0), (31, 2.25), (31, 2.5), (31, 2.75), (32, 2.0), (32, 2.25), (32, 2.5), (32, 2.75), (33, 2.0), (33, 2.25), (33, 2.5), (33, 2.75), (34, 2.0), (34, 2.25), (34, 2.5), (34, 2.75)], [(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), (20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)]]       

['RSI', 'MACD', 'EMA']
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)], [(11, 25, 9), (11, 25, 10), (11, 26, 9), 
(11, 26, 10), (12, 25, 9), (12, 25, 10), (12, 26, 9), (12, 26, 10), (13, 25, 9), (13, 25, 10), (13, 26, 9), (13, 26, 10)], [(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), (20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)]]     

['Bollinger', 'MACD', 'EMA']
[[(20, 2.0), (20, 2.25), (20, 2.5), (20, 2.75), (21, 2.0), (21, 2.25), (21, 2.5), (21, 2.75), (22, 2.0), (22, 2.25), (22, 2.5), (22, 2.75), (23, 2.0), (23, 2.25), (23, 2.5), (23, 2.75), (24, 2.0), (24, 2.25), (24, 2.5), (24, 2.75), (25, 2.0), (25, 2.25), (25, 2.5), (25, 2.75), (26, 2.0), (26, 2.25), (26, 2.5), (26, 2.75), (27, 2.0), (27, 2.25), (27, 2.5), (27, 2.75), (28, 2.0), (28, 2.25), (28, 2.5), (28, 2.75), (29, 2.0), (29, 2.25), (29, 2.5), (29, 2.75), (30, 2.0), (30, 2.25), (30, 2.5), (30, 2.75), (31, 2.0), (31, 2.25), (31, 2.5), (31, 2.75), (32, 2.0), (32, 2.25), (32, 2.5), (32, 2.75), (33, 2.0), (33, 2.25), (33, 2.5), (33, 2.75), (34, 2.0), (34, 2.25), (34, 2.5), (34, 2.75)], [(11, 25, 9), (11, 25, 10), (11, 26, 9), (11, 26, 10), (12, 25, 9), (12, 25, 10), (12, 26, 9), (12, 26, 10), (13, 25, 9), (13, 25, 10), (13, 26, 9), (13, 26, 10)], [(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), (20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)]]

['RSI', 'Bollinger', 'MACD', 'EMA']
[[(13, 70, 25), (13, 70, 30), (13, 75, 25), (13, 75, 30), (14, 70, 25), (14, 70, 30), (14, 75, 25), (14, 75, 30), (15, 70, 25), (15, 70, 30), (15, 75, 25), (15, 75, 30)], [(20, 2.0), (20, 2.25), (20, 2.5), (20, 2.75), (21, 2.0), (21, 2.25), (21, 2.5), (21, 2.75), (22, 2.0), (22, 2.25), (22, 2.5), (22, 2.75), (23, 2.0), (23, 2.25), (23, 2.5), (23, 2.75), (24, 2.0), (24, 2.25), (24, 2.5), (24, 2.75), (25, 2.0), (25, 2.25), (25, 2.5), (25, 2.75), (26, 2.0), (26, 2.25), (26, 2.5), (26, 2.75), (27, 2.0), (27, 2.25), (27, 2.5), (27, 2.75), (28, 2.0), (28, 2.25), (28, 2.5), (28, 2.75), (29, 2.0), (29, 2.25), (29, 2.5), (29, 2.75), (30, 2.0), (30, 2.25), (30, 2.5), (30, 2.75), (31, 2.0), (31, 2.25), (31, 2.5), (31, 2.75), (32, 2.0), (32, 2.25), (32, 2.5), (32, 2.75), (33, 2.0), (33, 2.25), (33, 2.5), (33, 2.75), (34, 2.0), (34, 2.25), (34, 2.5), (34, 2.75)], [(11, 25, 9), (11, 25, 10), (11, 26, 9), (11, 26, 10), (12, 25, 9), (12, 25, 10), (12, 26, 
9), (12, 26, 10), (13, 25, 9), (13, 25, 10), (13, 26, 9), (13, 26, 10)], [(20, 50, 0.0), (20, 50, 0.002), 
(20, 50, 0.004), (20, 50, 0.006), (20, 50, 0.008)]]
```